# Multiple writes to QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

I have a server and client program where it's convenient for the server to send out two messages to each client.  The server calls the write() function on each of the client sockets twice in a row.  On the client side, the readyread signal occurs, but when the client reads, it only gets the first message.  I fixed this by adding waitForBytesWritten() before each write() the server does, and this seemed to fix the problem.  However, I don't know why I can't just write to the buffer twice.  I would think there is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Does your client loop on the readyread signal? It is likely the signal is raised upon the first bytes of TCP data becoming available. That does not necessarily mean, however, that the second message has arrived.

Comment: What do you mean looping on the readyread signal?  Wouldn't it just get a new signal once the second message arrives?

Comment: If the first `readyReadSignal` does not give you all the bytes, then there will be emitted a second time.